# Changing the 'From Address' in Messaging.sendEmailMessage: Is It Possible?

Tags: apex, email, send-email

Is it possible to change the 'From Address' in Messaging.sendEmailMessage? According to the documentation, the 'From Address' is automatically populated with the email of the user under whom the Messaging.sendEmailMessage method is executed (The email address of the user calling the sendEmailMessage method is inserted in the From Address field of the email header and the Email Message record). Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

The [EmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm) object has both `FromAddress` and `FromName` fields. Specify these values to control the email and display name that will be used to send the emails. The address must be from the [`EmailMessageRelation`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessagerelation.htm) table with a `RelationType` of `FromAddress`.

Comment: Worth noting [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387977&type=1) explaining that you'll no longer be able to use Google (or Yahoo!) email addresses as sender addresses.

Comment: BTW, is there a reason you deleted your other answer (which I feel contributes to the discussion)?

Comment: @PhilW The other answer was for `Messaging.sendEmail`, rather than `Messaging.sendEmailMessage`. While debatably a good answer to the right question, it's the wrong answer to this question.